# How to install SolrNet.NHibernate?

Tags: nhibernate, solrnet

I tried `Install-Package Solrnet.NHibernate` on a new console application but it failed with this error:

```
Attempting to resolve dependency 'NHibernate.Core (≥ 2.1.2.4000)'.
Install-Package : Unable to resolve dependency 'NHibernate.Core (≥ 2.1.2.4000)'.
At line:1 char:16
+ install-package <<<<  solrnet.nhibernate
+ CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Install-Package], InvalidOperationException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PowerShell.Commands.InstallPackageCommand
```

Is this broken, and how do I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "NHibernate.Core" package was [renamed](http://nupackpackages.codeplex.com/workitem/3) to "NHibernate" a while ago. Heck, I even [supported](http://nupackpackages.codeplex.com/discussions/237211#PostContent_532014) that decision in a related discussion. Yet I forgot to update the SolrNet.NHibernate package. I guess I thought the NuGet team would batch transform all existing packages, but that never happened.

Anyway I just fixed the package and pushed it to the NuGet feed, so it all should work now.

Answer (score 0):

I would try to install the NHibernate package via NuGet before installing the SolrNet.NHibernate package as it appears that the Solrnet.NHibernate package is having trouble installing the NHibernate.Core package as a dependency and I do not see an NHibernate.Core package listed in NuGet. This may or may not work, but is worth a shot at least.

If this does not work. I would recommend getting the latest SolrNet binaries from the [SolrNet Google Code](http://code.google.com/p/solrnet/downloads/list) site and then following the [NHibernate Integration](http://code.google.com/p/solrnet/wiki/NHibernateIntegration) guidance.